# Can tab layout of LayoutAnchorablePane be changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I'm new to AvalonDock, and as I'm currently understanding it, whenever I float a LayoutAnchorable from a DockingManager, it will be put in a new LayoutAnchorablePane instead of a LayoutDocumentPane. The LayoutDocumentPane displays the tabs at the top of the window, but the floated LayoutAnchorable (inside a LayoutAnchorablePane) shows its tabs in the bottom of the window (if more anchorables are added to it). Is there any way to make them appear at the top instead of the bottom? Does anyone recognize this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl` (or any `TabControl` for that matter) has a property `TabStripPlacement` which you can set to `Top`. See the VS2010 [Theme.xaml](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version2.0/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.VS2010/Theme.xaml)